# Android: How to disable title in Achart engine line graph?

Tags: android, achartengine

I am implementing an achartengine line graph. I don't want to display the title when graph is executed. So how can i disable it? Any one of you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I am not sure about what you are asking,

But As much As I understand you want to remove Title from Chart,

For that you can do something like this where you have `created renderer` object

```
XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
renderer.setChartTitle("");// or pass null
```

Answer (score 0):

Your chart have following code
In that make tag as blank tag="";

```
setChartSettings(renderer, title, "Date",**tag**, dates.get(0)[0].getTime(),
                dates.get(0)[dates.get(0).length - 1].getTime(), 0, Double.parseDouble(max), Color.GRAY, Color.LTGRAY);
```

Comment: I am not able to disable the title. But i am able to display the y axis point after seeing ur code. But i am not able to display the dates on x-xis .Can you please post the example of the similar type?

Answer (score 0):

Better do not use the function

```
 MultipleSeriesRenderder.setChartTitle();
```

By default it is not showing any Chart Title.